# Context menu action

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I am using jquery context menu plugin https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu/blob/master/README.md

Now I have two option on menu 1. send message 2. view profile

When user click on 1. send message I want to open popup window in the center of the screen.
When user click on 2. View profile it should be send to them url (e.g. linkurl to profile)

I have never used context menu and I am using in php with passing user id dynamically. I got everything is works now but only don't know how to open popup window and send to url.

Here is javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#mythingy").contextPopup({
        title: "My Popup Menu",
        items: [{
            label: "Send message",
            icon: "icons/message.png",
            action: function() {
                // how to open popup window with form
            }
        },
        {
            label: "View profile",
            icon: "icons/zoom.png",
            action: function() {
                // how to add url here
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating to another page is easy - just assign to `location.href`.

```
location.href = "http://example.com/profile?id=" + id
```

jQuery doesn't provide an alternative for this, but if you *really* want to use jQuery, you can do this:

```
$(location).attr('href', "http://example.com/profile?id=" + id)
```

---

For popups, you can use the [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) plugin for jQuery.

```
<div id="message-form"> <!-- hide with display:none from css -->
  ...
</div>
```

to open:

```
$.fancybox($("#message-form"))
```

---

If you want to open a separate browser window instead of opening a popup inside the page, you can use `window.open()`:

```
var w2=window.open();
$(w2.document.body).append($("#message-form").clone());
```

Comment: First location.href works for me. Thanks a lot. Now I am trying to implement fancybox as it is not included into the site. Just quick question. Is there way to open popup window instead of fancybox?

Comment: `window.open()` creates a new native browser window you can paint into, but you can expect popup blockers to stand in your way.

Comment: @pixelngrain added an example of `window.open`

Comment: If you want to draw your own fancybox, just append two fixed `div`s to the page. one to darken the background, one with the contents - play with `padding`, `margin`s, `border`s, `border-radius` and `box-shadow`. IE8 doesn't support the latter two, but I guess you can live with that ;-)

Comment: Thanks I am trying this now and get back to you in an hour or so.